# Render the alpha channel into an RGBA .jpg file with 3ds Max and maxscript

Tags: scripting, rendering, alpha, 3dsmax, 3ds

I have simple script where I render an object with the following command:

```
Render camera: $Camera001 outputfile: "test.jpg" outputsize:[1920,1080] vfb:off outputHDRbitmap: true
```

However, the output file is 24 Bit RGB, I wonder if there is a possibility to render RGBA with the same command or another method with the some simplicity?

I could only find solutions with bitmaps that went over my head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use PNG with alpha instead of JPG.

The command is totally correct, however as a preparation step you may also need to access PNG settings with maxscript, as you normally do with this PNG configuration dialog:

[image: PNG settings 3ds max]

```
pngio.setType #true48
pngio.setAlpha true
pngio.setInterlaced false
```

Complete documentation for pngio you may find here: [https://help.autodesk.com/...F08AA370DEB8_htm](https://help.autodesk.com/view/3DSMAX/2016/ENU/?guid=__files_GUID_346BAD46_D9DF_4D27_8734_F08AA370DEB8_htm)